# how to fix encoding issue with sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm setting up my SQLite on an android studio in both my pc and mac, but when I open the databases file using txt at the device file explorer, [This is the db file using text open in the android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCg74.png) this is the error. 
Then I try to fix this by change encoding to GBK. It is still unable to show the data. Also, I try to save the db file and open in SQLite viewer plugin in google chrome, it's said that the table was not found. And I was really sure database was working fine with my teammate computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio cannot open SQLite files directly. The file according to the screen shot. Appears to be a valid SQLite file that is the first 16 characters appear to be **The header string: "SQLite format 3\000"** as described in [Database File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#database_header).

What you need to do is place the file in the **assets** folder (your may need to create the folder) of the project (I suggest copying the file outside of Android Studio) (**databases** folder within the **assets** folder if using [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)).

Your App should then copy the database (the file) into it's location (typically the directory data/data/your_package/databases, not that you should hard code this but get it using the Context's `getDatabasePath` method), if the database file doesn't exist, and then access the database as an SQLiteDatabase object.

**SQLiteAssetHelper**, as linked above, makes this relatively simple. However, it does not appear to handle Android Pie. There are numerous posts regrading copying a pre-existing database e.g. [The Answer Here (copes with Android Pie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336900/a-pre-populated-database-does-not-work-at-api-28-throws-no-such-table-exceptio/55346290#55346290).

Re the comment

> how to set back the file editor default as db type, because my file inside of Android studio was txt type

Use File/Settings/Editor/File Types.

Answer (score 0):

You can not open db as text file. when you talk about Unicode you are talking about characters but db data is not some characters like a text file. It is binary file. db may contain images or any other binary data.

You can use SQLite Browser: [https://sqlitebrowser.org](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Comment: how to set back the file editor default as db type, because my file inside of Android studio was txt type.

Comment: @learnisgood you can not change Android Studio editors but if you use Windows OS you can right click on any file select `properties` and select `change` button from `opens with` section. also see this https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-file-associations-in-windows-2624477

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a free tool called SQLite Studio to create, modify, delete SQLite databases, tables and data.  https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt

In a pinch, you can also use SQLite from a command line.  On a mac, you would open your terminal window to do this.