# Cursor count of pre-populated database is always 0

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I've got a prefilled database in assets. I copy this database after first launch and try to query, but `cursor` never has data. It shows all columns of selected `table` but `getCount()` is always 0. Where is my mistake? Here is my code:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context mycontext;
    private String DB_PATH;    
    private static String DB_NAME = "championBuilds.db";//the extension may be .sqlite or .db
    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;   

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException, SQLException {
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
        this.mycontext=context;
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.app.myapp/databases/";
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if (dbexist) {
            //System.out.println("Database exists");
            opendatabase();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
            createdatabase();
        }
    }

    public void createdatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if(dbexist) {
            //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copydatabase();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }   

    private boolean checkdatabase() {
        //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
        boolean checkdb = false;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        }
        return checkdb;
    }

    private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
            myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();
    }

    public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null) {
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Books";
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        //if TABLE has rows
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //Loop through the table rows
            do {
                Book book = new Book();
                book.id = cursor.getInt(0);
                book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));

                // Add book to books
                books.add(book);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        myDataBase.close();
        return books;
    }
}
```

And there is how I call these methods:

```
try {
    db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    List<Book> books = db.getAllBooks();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you **1)** use the tool that you used to create the pre-existing database to open the database, check that it has rows (if not add them) and save/close the tool (repeat the above until you are sure it has saved rows). **2)** Delete the current database file from the assets folder. **3)** Re-copy the database file into the assets folder. **4)** Delete the App's data or uninstall the App and then rerun the App.

Comment: You may also wish to consider the answer given at [A pre-populated database does not work at API 28 throws “no such table” exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336900/a-pre-populated-database-does-not-work-at-api-28-throws-no-such-table-exceptio/55346290#55346290). As I believe that your code would not work for later versions of Android due to using `this.getReadableDatabase();` in the **createdatabase()** method.

Comment: I create and prefill this data base out of Android Studio and application. I create it Eclipse using SQLiteHelper. Everything worked fine: I could easily create db and tables, fill it and then query. Then I copied this db to my application...

Comment: I'm absolutely sure it has rows. And I can easily query them in Eclipse, but nothing work in Android Studio