# data lost after copying sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I copy a database from assets after that table of data is going lost

this is android studio and  copy database from assets

error is = no such table: tbltexts (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tbltexts

my dbname=texts.db

**THIS ERROR IS ON ANDROID PIE**

```
public class Databasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.nooshindroid.Rosary/databases/";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "texts.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String tblname ="tbltexts";
    public static final String id="id";
    public static final String arabic ="Arabic_text";
    public static final String english ="English_text";
    public static final String counter ="Counter";
    public static final String goal ="Goal";
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    public Databasehelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);
             this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

}
```

---

```
public class DbHandler {


    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private  String name;
    private Databasehelper dbHelper;
    public DbHandler(Context context){
        dbHelper=new Databasehelper(context);
    }
    public void open(){
        database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public  void close(){
       database.close();
    }

    public String display(int row,int field){

        Cursor cursor=database.query(dbHelper.tblname,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
            cursor.moveToPosition(row);
           name=cursor.getString(field);
        return name;
    }



    public boolean insert(String txtarab,String txtenglish,int goal) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(dbHelper.arabic, txtarab);
        cv.put(dbHelper.english, txtenglish);
        cv.put(dbHelper.goal,goal);
        long result = database.insert(dbHelper.tblname, null, cv);
        database.close();

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Integer count(){
        Cursor cursor=database.query(dbHelper.tblname,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        int s=cursor.getCount();
        return s;
    }
    public void delete(int id){
        database.delete(dbHelper.tblname,"id="+id,null);
    }
    public void update(String arab, String englsih, int id){
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(dbHelper.arabic,arab);
        contentValues.put(dbHelper.english,englsih);
        database.update(dbHelper.tblname,contentValues,"id="+id,null);
    }

    public void counterupdate(int id,int counter){
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(dbHelper.counter,counter);
        database.update(dbHelper.tblname,contentValues,"id="+id,null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is proper but. if you delete any table at runtime then please put comment temporary and check, it may delete tablet somewhere

Comment: I suggest you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336900/a-pre-populated-database-does-not-work-at-api-28-throws-no-such-table-exceptio/55346290#55346290)

Answer (score 1):

You should not hard-code the database path, there is no guaranty that it will be `/data/data/<package_id>/databases`, for example on my phone (Android Pie, API 26) it is `/data/user/<user_id>/<package_id>/databases`. The documentation even warns that the path may change, as application can be moved to adopted storage.

If the path is wrong (and if the exception from `copyDataBase()` is catched) you end up with the empty database created automatically by the `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

A solution could be to replace :

```
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
```

with :

```
String outFileName = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
```

Comment: Thank you bwt . I solved my problem with sqliteassetshelper library