# Doesn't work pre-populated sqlite database when I Install from Google store

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

In my app I use pre-populated database. I copy it from assets. And when api is 28 I receved empty database.
I changed my SQLiteOpenHelper as written in a similar question ([A pre-populated database does not work at API 28 throws "no such table" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336900/a-pre-populated-database-does-not-work-at-api-28-throws-no-such-table-exceptio)):

```java
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
...
    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
        }
        super.onConfigure(db);
    }
}
```

And it works when I install my app from Android Studio, but doesn't work when I get my app from the Google store.